# python - Values not being pulled from XML

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<root>
  <subroot id="someID">
    <val1 value="a"/>
    <val2 value="b"/>
    <val3 value="c"/>
    <val4 value="1"/>
    <val5 value="2"/>
    <val6 value="3"/>
    <otherval value="xyz"/>
  </subroot>
  <subroot id="anotherID">
    <val1 value="aa"/>
    <val2 value="bb"/>
    <val3 value="cc"/>
    <val4 value="11"/>
    <val5 value="22"/>
    <val6 value="33"/>
    <otherval value="xxyyzz"/>
  </subroot>
  .
  .
  .
  .
</root>
```

I am trying to retrieve the values in each tag. For example, my desired output would be:

```
val1=a
val2=b
val3=c
val4=1
val5=2
val6=3
otherval=xyz
```

Here is my non-working code that produces blanks, ie `val1="", val2=""...`:

```
def getValues(self):
    from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
    import json

    file = open('myfile.xml','r')
    data = file.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    rows = dom.getElementsByTagName("root")[0].getElementsByTagName("subroot")
    valueString = ""
    for row in rows:
        valueString = valueString+json.dumps(
        {
        'val1': row.getAttribute("val1"),
        'val2': row.getAttribute("val2"),
        'val3': row.getAttribute("val3"),
        'val4': row.getAttribute("val4"),
        'val5': row.getAttribute("val5"),
        'val6': row.getAttribute("val6"),
        'other': row.getAttribute("otherval")},
        sort_keys=True,
        indent=4)+","
    response_generator = ( "["+valueString[:-1]+"]" )
    return HttpResponse(response_generator)
    otherval=xyz
```

I know that thisactually produces JSON but thats not important. The important thing is being able to extract the values and then I can do whatever with them afterwards.

Can someone show me what I'm missing here?
Also, should I change my XML so all the `val1,val2,val3....` are just called `val`?

Thanks.

Comment: In answer to your question at the end, yes. In any XML the tag names define what it is you are dealing with - in this case a value, then the attributes or tag value give you the data contained by the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to structure your data as follows:

```xml
<root>
  <subroot id="someID">
    <value id="1">a</value>
    <value id="2">b</value>
    <value id="3">c</value>
    <value id="4">d</value>
    <value id="5">2</value>
    <value id="6">3</value>
    <value id="other">xyz</value>
  </subroot>
  <subroot id="anotherID">
    <value id="1">aa</value>
    <value id="2">bb</value>
    <value id="3">cc</value>
    <value id="4">11</value>
    <value id="5">22</value>
    <value id="6">33</value>
    <value id="other">xxyyzz</value>
  </subroot>
</root>
```

Then, to parse, I suggest the etree library - it's in the standard library for Python and I've found it far nicer to work with than anything else. It's just a simple case of iterating through the subroots and value elements and extracting the data.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree

xml = ElementTree.parse("test.xml")

root = xml.getroot()

all = {}

for group in root.findall("subroot"):
    temp = {}
    for value in group.findall("value"):
        temp[value.get("id")] = value.text
    all[group.get("id")] = temp
```

all will then be:

```py
{'someID': {'1': 'a', '3': 'c', '2': 'b', '5': '2', '4': 'd', '6': '3', 'other': 'xyz'}, 'anotherID': {'1': 'aa', '3': 'cc', '2': 'bb', '5': '22', '4': '11', '6': '33', 'other': 'xxyyzz'}}
```

You could also do this as a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dict%20comprehension#dictionaries):

```py
all = {group.get("id"): {value.get("id"): value.text for value in group.findall("value")} for group in root.findall("subroot")}
```

Note that this is a little hard to read and will fall apart if you try to do anything more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the design suggestion. I've reworked my code to produce this design and have my XML document ready. I'm not sure if your code works though. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @eoinzy I've run it under both Python 2 and Python 3, runs fine in both cases.

Comment: Hmm, thats weird. When I output `all` I just get `someIDanotherID`.

Comment: @eoinzy My guess there is something is wrong with your value elements, did you change your XML to match mine? Including the tags being value not val? (or obviously the code to match your XML).

Comment: Ye I've copied and pasted your XML example above, as well as your code. The only thing I added was `return HttpResponse(all)` since I'm using `Django` so I need to output to the webpage.

Comment: @eoinzy Well, as my example definitely works for me, it must be something you are doing your end. If you update the question with the updated version (add it all on at the end), I'll take a look.

Comment: I can get the code to print out either the ID, eg `someIDanotherID` or else the value IDs, eg `other123456` but not the values, eg `abc123`. Are you using my original XML, or your new XML suggestion? Coz I've moved to your suggestion. Maybe I can switch back.

Comment: @eoinzy: My code was written to work with the XML I provided. I can't think of why it didn't work - did you try just copy and pasting my example and running it as - is and seeing if it works in that form? It seems so odd it works perfectly for me, but not for you.

Answer (score 1):

`val1` etc are not attributes of the `subroot` row. They are child rows, each of which has a `value` attribute which contains the data you want. You'll need to get the children of each `subroot` and iterate through those, calling `row.getAttribute("value")` on each.

And as Lattyware says, yes you should rename your elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> rows = dom.getElementsByTagName("root")[0].getElementsByTagName("subroot")

>>> v = rows[0].getElementsByTagName("val1")[0]

>>> v.getAttribute("value")
u'a'
```

i would sugguest you to use ElementTree much easier to understand.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
>>> root = et.fromstring(data)
>>> v = root.find("*/val1")
>>> v.get("value")
'a'
```